# Using LINQ against a watin table syntax issue

Tags: c#, linq, watin

I'm trying to get around the fact that watin table access is very slow by using LINQ to search the table (I have yet to find out if this is actually faster). There are about 4500 rows in the table I'm looking thus performance is important.

Ideally from my code I would like to have a collection of TableRow objects based on the LINQ query but I'm struggling a bit with the syntax.
My code so far is:

```
var Rows = main.TableRows.Where(x => (x.TableCells[0].ToString() == "Investments") && (x.TableCells[1].ToString() == DistributionId) && (x.TableCells[2].ToString() == RiskNumber));
```

This does not return a TableRowCollection and I'm not sure how to get it to do this?

Alternatively if you know that this will not be faster and there is a faster/ more sensible  way I would greatly appreciate being informed.

Comment: it should return something like `IEnumerable<TableRow>`,if you want to put them in a list you can use `ToList`, why do you need `TableRowCollection` ?

Comment: I just thought it would handier because I can still operate the returned rows as rows by going cell to cell etc.